# Deal with Oracle date ranges

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I need to write a query in Oracle 11g r2 that retrieves records if a date range is inside another date range. If a null value is returned, then I need to take the very next interval.

For example:

```
Input: March 01 2014 - March 31 2014
First Interval range: Jan 01 2014 - June 31 2014
Second Interval range: Feb 01 2015 - Mar 31 2015
Third Interval range: Sept 01 2015 - Dec 31 2015
```

The record is inside the First Interval, so return that.

Second Example:

```
Input: Oct 01 2014 - Oct 31 2014
First Interval range: Jan 01 2014 - June 31 2014
Second Interval range: Feb 01 2015 - Mar 31 2015
Third Interval range: Sept 01 2015 - Dec 31 2015
```

The record is not included in any range, so I take the Second Interval (the next range that occurs after Input).

Comment: Please show sample data and desired results, with particular emphasis on how you define the intervals.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff Find the range 09/01/2013 10/28/2013 in the following set:  
52492 1009 08/01/2013 10/31/2013  
52492 1280 11/01/2013 12/31/9999  
  
Find 52492 1009 08/01/2013 10/31/2013  
  
--*************************************************************************--  
  
Find the range 03/01/2013 03/31/2013 in the following set:  
  
52492 1009 08/01/2013 10/31/2013  
52492 1280 11/01/2013 12/31/9999  
  
No record found, I take the next one:  
52492 1009 08/01/2013 10/31/2013

Comment: ^ This may have gone unanswered because useful information was added only to the comments. Always add material to question posts themselves - and show what you tried. For now, and since it is an old question, voting to close as too broad.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine them into 1 statement like below, but performance-wise would probably be better in a stored proc where you can check 
1) Look for a result in the range specified.
2) Only if no result found, then do the second part of the query to find the next interval after the specified range.

```
WITH 
  inRange as
  (
     SELECT 1 as tmpID, Interval_Id 
     FROM your_table
     WHERE :dateStart BETWEEN Interval_Start AND Interval_End
          OR :dateEnd BETWEEN Interval_Start AND Interval_End
  ),
  outRange as 
  (
     SELECT 1 as tmpID, Interval_Id 
     FROM
     (
        SELECT Interval_Id 
        from your_table
        where Interval_Start > :dateEnd
        order by Interval_Start ASC
     )
     WHERE ROWNUM = 1
  )
SELECT NVL(a.Interval_Id, b.Interval_Id) as Result
FROM inRange a
RIGHT JOIN outRange b on a.tmpID = b.tmpID
```

Notes:

- The tmpID is just an artifact to stick the 2 results together. As I
  mentioned above, it would be better to break into 2 queries.
- RIGHT JOIN - could also use FULL OUTER JOIN
- For some reason the 2nd part of the query doesn't work inline, so that's why I used the CTE.
- Assumes that none of your intervals overlap